# How to use VantaJS in SvelteKit

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, svelte

How to use [Vanta JS](https://github.com/tengbao/vanta) from [SvelteKit](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit) project? 
I've tried,in `+page.svelte`,

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import VANTA from "vanta";
    import * as THREE from 'three';

    VANTA.NET({
        el: "#home-page",
        mouseControls: true,
        ...
    })
</script>

<div id="home-page">
    ...
</div>
```

But could not import VANTA in that way. 
I also tried to use CDN from `app.html` but no luck.

### Edited

Thanks to [answer of H.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74235457/how-to-use-vantajs-in-sveltekit/74235837#74235837), I could add the Vanta JS background on my SvelteKit page. 
However, the rendering result is different with the one of CodePen.

```html
<script>
    import * as THREE from 'three';
    import NET from 'vanta/dist/vanta.net.min';

    function vanta(node) {
        NET({
            el: node,
            THREE: THREE,
            mouseControls: true,
            touchControls: true,
            gyroControls: false,
            minHeight: 200.00,
            minWidth: 200.00,
            scale: 1.00,
            scaleMobile: 1.00,
            color: 0x7accfe,
            backgroundColor: 0x010f18
        })
    }

</script>

<div use:vanta/>
```

On SvelteKit webapp,
[image]

On CodePen,
[image]

In the browser console, I got this message: 
`THREE.Material: 'vertexColors' parameter is undefined.`

I installed Vanta JS and Three.js like this,

```bash
npm install -D vanta
npm install -D three
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SvelteKit you need to make sure the code only runs on the client. Either use `onMount` or better yet, an action which gives you the node.

You also have to supply the Three.js module to Vanta as a property and should import the desired effect directly from `vanta/dist`:

```html
<script>
    import * as THREE from 'three';
    import NET from 'vanta/dist/vanta.net.min';

    function vanta(node) {
        NET({
            el: node,
            THREE: THREE,
            color: 0x000000,
        })
    }
</script>

<div use:vanta/>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I faced another issue with this solution. Added the detail on the post. How can I solve the rendering issue?

Comment: The issue is temporarily solved, in the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

The rendering issue was caused by version mis-matching between Vanta JS and Three.js.

> THREE.Material: 'vertexColors' parameter is undefined.

At this moment of writing,

- the Vanta JS version is 0.5.24
- This error is coming from Three.js version greater than 0.140.2 (read this [thread](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/vertexcolor-parameter-not-working-in-v-0-142-0-but-works-in-v0-140-2-or-below/40607)).

Thus I had to hard-point the Three.js version like this.

```bash
npm install -D three@0.140.2
```

As the result, rendering on SvelteKit webapp became exactly same as CodePen examples.